# Function return doesn't work properly

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make django rest frameworki api work, **I made file api.py** with function called keyword_organic that returns output like this:

```
{'u1': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow', 'u2': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_color'}
```

if I use this:

```
ress = keyword_organic(keyword)
print ress
```

**Then it prints the exact output I gave above.** So to my understanding 'ress' variable holds this string correct?

However, when I try to use this function and pass output too serializer it just doesn't work.. here is the code:

```
ress = keyword_organic(keyword)

serializer = SemrushSerializer(data=ress)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
```

However if I just make new variable:

```
var = {'u1': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow', 'u2': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_color'}
```

And pass this one directly to serializer it works (`data=var`)

I am also pasting bottom of `keyword_organic` function from `api.py`, in case something is wrong there:

```
# ....
listof = str(listof)
listof = listof.translate(None, '{}')
table = string.maketrans('[]', '{}')
listof = listof.translate(table)

return listof
```

Comment: Is your function returning the json as string?

Comment: yes, but I think it doesn't matter because if I just make new variable and put that string there it passes it to serializer and into database.

Comment: @NemaGa: of course it matters; a string is not a dictionary. `var` is a dictionary, `ress` is a string.

Comment: It also looks like you are trying to produce Python-like syntax in a string from an original Python object. There are probably *far more efficient* ways of doing what you want to produce, without producing a string.

Comment: @RohitJain: the returned string is not valid JSON; it uses single quotes, not double.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah yes.. Didn't notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `keyword_organic()` function returns a *string*, one that happens to look like Python literals (syntax to produce a dictionary with string keys and values). It is *not* a Python dictionary.

`var`, on the other hand, is a dictionary. To re-create the `ress` value, you'd have to set `var` to:

```
var = "{'u1': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow', 'u2': 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_color'}"
```

Note the quotes; printing `var` will still produce the same output as printing `ress`.

You *could* turn `ress` into a dictionary using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
ress_as_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(ress)
```

but you'd be far better off having your `keyword_organic()` function return a Python dictionary rather than a string. Judging by the minimal amount you posted you are doing something very weird indeed (turning a list into a dictionary by producing a string?).

Answer (score 1):

You need to **pass a dictionary to a serializer as `data` argument** instead of passing a string.

**Why the code with `ress` does not work?**

This is because you are passing a string to the `SemrushSerializer` which expects a dictionary of data and not string object. Without this, the serializer won't be able to generate mappings for the fields and won't be valid.

**Why code with `var` works?**

Here, you passed `var` as a dictionary containing `u1` and `u2` keys. The serializer could map the input keys to its fields and was valid hence saving the object correctly.